# how can i make the 'remember me' in one line

Tags: html, css

(i'm a noobie)
i want the remember me text in a single line.
i tried making it as a inline but not getting it into one line.
i want the solution using basic html and css.
how can i make linear gradient coloring in css.

```
       p{
        font-weight: bold;
        display: inline;
       }
    
    
           </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box">
    <div class="one">
  <h2>Login Form</h2>
  <p>Email:</p>
  <input type="text" name="email" class="textbox">
  <p>Password:</p>
  <input type="password" name="password" class="textbox">
  <p><input type="checkbox">Remember Me</p>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="button">
       </div>
       </div>
</body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

did you try to google this? I found a [solution](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/html-force-div-text-one-line#:%7E:text=To%20force%20the%20text%20in,to%20clip%20the%20remaining%20text.) from the first suggestion in google. This is for the one line feature you asked btw and code is in css:

```
#nospace {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```